# Mobile Safari Not Loading Images When Using AJAX/JQUERY

Tags: ios, mobile, safari

I have been fighting over an issue with Safari on the iPhone and iPad.

I'm developing a mobile single page app, of which for the most part is working. Except when it comes to any kind of AJAX injecting of images or toggling CSS classes that show images. When debugging I see it just polling and polling and polling some more trying to get the image asset.

Can someone tell me why I would be having this issue? Also if it's some kind of memory limit I am hitting what  is the suggested workaround and or alternatives..

Comment: Can you Post some code?

Comment: Does it work on a regular browser? Also, try enabling the mobile safari developer's console, there might be an error message there that could be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes it works fine in a normal browser. And as stated I had it in the debugger and there are no errors. I can see the image trying to load but it does not load as if it can't due to a network problem but it's not a network problem at all as the page loads fine. This only happens when the item is being injected via AJAX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found the answer to my issue.

Through this thread on Apple's developer forum.

[IOS6 / Safari limits one connection per server](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4466216?start=0&tstart=0)

My web app, has functionality to broadcast realtime updates to anyone browsing the site of which uses long polling. Thus anything else such as images can't load via Ajax because the active connection is being taken up at the time.